# CollectionView layerMask "jitter" when applied while scrolling

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I’m working on a view controller prototype consisting of a collectionView with the following requirements:

- There is a single background image visible
- Sections can “collapse” similar to an accordion view
- The first view (called “main header” from now on) in the list “sticks” to the top of the screen so the button on the bottom remains visible while scrolling
- Section headers “stick” below the main header and push each other out of the way when the next section header docks in the top. This is just like the default behavior of section headers in tableView.
- The main header, section headers, and cells all have transparent backgrounds

I’ve decided to use UICollectionView for my solution. I could have tried to work around UITableView, but I wanted more control over the animation during collapsing and expansion of sections. It also allows me finer-grained control over the positioning of views on screen by subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

There’s an issue due to the transparency requirement. Because all views have clear backgrounds, when overlap occurs (due to sticky main and section headers) we can see all cells at once when ideally the cells should go “underneath” their section headers. My solution here was to find the frame difference between overlapping views and use a layer mask to “hide” the part of the overlapping view that would normally be hidden if the background was opaque.

For some reason, while scrolling it looks like the frame of the layer mask is not being updated at the same time as the scrollView’s contentOffset resulting in a slight, but noticeable “delay.” I’ve tried the following approaches to fix the issue (all of which exhibited the same behavior):

1. Use CADisplayLink and update the layer masks every frame. To determine when view frames intersected, I tried both UIView.frame as well as UIView.layer.presentation().frame.
2. Use UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes on my UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass for calculating layer mask frames instead of the views themselves.
3. Build a custom UICollectionViewLayout subclass and use its layout attributes for calculating layer mask frames (eliminating possibility it was something due to UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass).

I have a few theories for this behavior. Maybe there’s a sync issue due to collectionView updating the view positions in a separate pass of the run loop from when contentOffset changes, the layer mask’s frame change is due to some implicit animation, or layer masks don’t render properly when placed on half-points. Wrapping in an actions-disabled CATransaction ruled out the implicit animation issue and I would have though the displayLink while reading layer.presentation() for mask frame calculations would have ruled out the sync issue.

Other interesting item of note, this behavior does not occur when using UITableView which is why I was thinking it could be related to the run loop.

Below is a link to a sample project on my github page illustrating the behavior discussed above. The cells in this sample have a background color set by default to better illustrate the issue (it’s hard to see when they’re transparent).

https://github.com/irtemed88/ScrollJitterTest-iOS

Any help or pointers as to why this behavior occurs would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The solution was similar to an approach I had tried during testing.

The issue appears to be related to the run loop (or at least when the scrollView's content offset gets updated). Instead of calculating the layer mask frame based off of the views in the collection view, I'm using a custom UICollectionViewLayout and corresponding UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes for each item to calculate the mask frames. It appears the layout attributes are updated in sync with the repositioning of the views on screen. Keying off those values when setting the mask fixes the problem.